# Group all ngDialogs in a factory and calling them from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So in order to have the ngDialogs centrilized into a specific place and not wandering about, I though about having a factory, let's call it modal.js, which would have a list of all the modals in a switch. Something like this:

```js
.factory('Modal', [function() {
  var modal = {};

  return {
    get : function(option) {
      switch(option) {
        case 'modal1':
          modal = {
            template: 'modal1.php',
            controller: 'modalController',
            resolve: {
              $dep: function() {
                return 'dep';
              },
              dip: function() {
                return 'dup'
              }
            }
          };
          break;

        case 'modal2':
          modal = {
            template: 'modal2.php',
            controller: 'modalController2',
            resolve: {
              $dep2: function() {
                return item.dep2;
              },
              dip2: function() {
                return item.dip2;
              }
            }
          };
          break;
      }

      return modal;
    }
  }
}]);
```

And then my plan was to call it through a directive. Let's call it open-modal.js.

```js
.directive("openModal", ['ngDialog', 'Modal', function(ngDialog, Modal) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      return elem.bind('click', function() {
        var modal = Modal.get(attrs.modalName) // Modal.get('modal1');
        ngDialog.open(modal);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

The problem that I have is basically with the `modal2`. I am not able to get the item from the resolve, obviously, because it isn't part of the controller. My question is: Is it possible to find a workaround in order to maintain it this way?

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. What I am doing is using the $broadcast in order to call the function that will be in each Controller, so the resolve will be able to work properly.

```js
.factory('Modal', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  var modal = {};

  return {
    get : function(option, params) {
      switch(option) {
        case 'modal1':
          $rootScope.$broadcast('modal:controller1:modal1');
          break;
        case 'modal2':
          $rootScope.$broadcast('modal:controller2:modal2');
          break;
      }

      return modal;
    }
  }
}]);
```